# How Do I Get Rid of "Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0"?

Tags: nvidia, wine, randr

**My short question is:**

How do I get rid of the RandR error below, while still using a proprietaty nVidia driver package (e.g. 304) ?

**The gore follows.**

A fresh install of wine 1.5 (latest, from ubuntu-wine ppa) leaves me with the following when I run `winecfg` for the spanking-first time, and note I have *not* touched `winetricks` yet, *nor* does `~/.wine` exist :

```
me@mine:~$ winecfg
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/me/.wine'
**err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.**
[err repeats at least 4x more]
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
[fixme repeats at least 2x more]
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
...
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x112e8d0, overlapped 0x112e8dc): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/me/.wine' has been updated.
**err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.**
[err repeats sporadically]
```

Removing the current `nVidia` packages and (re)installing `Nouveau` gets rid of the RandR error, but gives me copious errors when I launch anything requiring shader model 3, e.g. Eve Online, my only motivation to wrestle with Wine, currently.  For it to run, I know I need the proprietary driver, and so Nouveau is not a solution for me - unless y'all know how to get sm3 support with the open stuff currently available, which would be just fabulous and tell me please.

I have gathered from WineHQ that the `fixme`s and the majority of `err`s are an innocuous "don't look behind the curtain" type of wish-list verbosity.

This Broken nVidia RandR thing, though, is something I'd like to deal with in order to get to, well, the other graphics issues I'm crossing my fingers about (in particular, a manual modification of wine1.5's shader model 3 detection routine to allow for my **nVidia GeForce Go 7900 GS**, which is one of the few sm3-compliant laptop gpu's to come out before sm4-type features were also implemented, leaving it out of consideration by the current Wine developers who seem to use sm4-ish flags to test for sm3 suport).

In order to tinker with my other woes, I must first eliminate the non-starters.  This RandR is one.  I think it's different from the other related posts in that I have not attempted to run anything other than `winecfg` itself to elicit the error, as opposed to a third party program.

```
PS `uname -a` --> Linux aestrid 3.8.0-12-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 7 17:17:00 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

PPS `raring` up-to-the-minute update/dist-upgrade
```

How to solve this ?

PPPS If Henri Verbeet is listening.

Comment: Same problem here with a GeForce 320m

Comment: @nbm - just meant as idea or suggestion - deinstall wine, avoid dual-boot with win-x - test this nvidia-driver (but remove all drivers you have tried out before)...http://askubuntu.com/questions/311151/how-can-i-install-nvidia-driver-gt-520-and-cuda-5-0-in-ubuntu13-04/311154#311154

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Install `winetricks` and run `winetricks orm=backbuffer glsl=disable`. This will fix the error mentioned.

Comment: in case you cannot live without wine, not without samba, and not without windows, then this option with winetricks is then probably creating less trouble, but only to your desktopand  not to mine or not to those, who want to live without dual-boot like in this situation and therefore am then one of those Linuxers who are less touchable ...   :o) ...

Comment: @dschinn1001: I agree, but the user asked something wine-related. ;)

Comment: + is ok + users should know this too + more ubuntu-related installation and less wine-windows-samba-installation is making hardware living longer ... + ...  :oD

Comment: + this was the effect of two months ago to all smartphones to get finally the better appearance optically + simply an update of this header like mine I tried as to define a new standard but it is still open if this will be accepted by consortiums ??? + http://www.nosy-x.com/beispiel001.pdf (beispiel=german word for example)

Comment: This one liner has no effect on the RandR warnings on my system.

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: This didn't change anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm moving far from the solution here, but if you did your own installation with the script provided by nvidia, I would try to add ppa of [xorg-edgers](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers), update and install the driver prepared by them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

It saved me lots of troubles when trying to install official nvidia drivers in the past and since then I had no troubles at all with wine or anything.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the bug happens when wine try switching the resolution using XRandr extension.

so to resolve the issue you must disable or prevent wine from this behavior

go ahead and install **Q4Wine** from synaptic package manager and launch it

next go to **Programs** tab in the main window and right click on the prefix you are using by  and choose **Configure fake drive settings**

in the **Fake Drive Settings** window go to Video > X11 Driver and set UseRandR to N as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRmRa.jpg

Comment: Hello. Do you know this works on this 9 year old question?

Comment: Indeed It's a 9 years old question but the solution proposed didn't work for me neither for other people  and i found this solution by trial and error  that works without disabling GLSL or setting orm to a specific value  I'm using MXlinux 21 with WINE 7.0

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to restrict your X server to only one screen resolution by adding one line to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in `Screen` section:

`Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080 +0+0"`

Replace `1920x1080` with the supported resolution you need.

It's explained in detail at Wine FAQ:

https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Broken_NVIDIA_RandR_detected.2C_falling_back_to_RandR_1.0