# How do I kill the x-server?

Tags: lightdm, gdm, xserver

Every time I try to kill the x-server,

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

so that I can install the latest Nvidia drivers, I get an error message.

```
stop: Unknown instance:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that depends on which DM you are using:   sudo service lightdm stop --> Ubuntu with Unity;   sudo service kdm stop --> Kubuntu;     sudo service gdm stop ..;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I did a little more digging around and found that I could just use pgrep to find its PID and then kill it.

> pgrep dm -l
>
> sudo kill (insert PID here)

Comment: I think this is a bit dangerous. You could kill the RAID software manager (mdadm).

Answer (score 59):

1. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to TTY.
2. Log in.
3. Run:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm stop
   ```

   LightDM and Xserver should be stopped now (check with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, which is your current Xorg session, it should not show any desktop now).
4. Do your things.
5. Run the following command to start lightdm and xorg again:

   ```
   sudo service lightdm start
   ```

Good Luck!

Comment: That's exactly what I did except halfway through #3 I was stopped with an error message.

Comment: That sounds mysterious ;) my best guess is that lightdm is not runnig at all and you are using some other Display manger... With cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager, you can find out which Display Manager you are currently using, with sudo service --status-all you can find out which services are currently running. Maybe that helps to find out why there is no lightdm instance and what Diplay manager runs instead..

Comment: For me it was `gdm3` rather than `lightdm`. Also my desktop environment in recent ubuntu was running on the F1 terminal, not F7, so I did the `sudo service gdm3 stop` on some other free terminal - the F3 one.

Answer (score 8):

You will need the help of `htop` or `top`. Write down the PID number of the process you want to kill (in this case, `Xorg`). Once you have the PID, run the below command in a root shell (`sudo -s`):

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

For example:

```
kill -9 1234
```

You should then be able to install the NVidia drivers.

Comment: Thanks! actually realized this and started typing while you answered.

Comment: Do you have nvidia-card with CUDA ? - for this case there is special driver - you can read all this at my post here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/311151/how-can-i-install-nvidia-driver-gt-520-and-cuda-5-0-in-ubuntu13-04/311154#311154

Answer (score 7):

Try running `sudo service gdm stop`.

The reason your command may be resulting in that output is because `lightdm` isn't your Display Manager.

In addition to `gdm`, also try `xdm` and `kdm`.

Answer (score 3):

/etc/init.d/lightdm stop maybe? And why you can't install nvidia drivers from software center?

Comment: They're outdated, the NVIDIA website always has the most recent drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Ok had the GTX 970 installation Problem under Ubuntu 14.04 too.
Sometime i was able to start Ubuntu with the standart drivers and sometime not.

However, this should hopefully fix the Problem:
After switching from IGP (I7 4770 with HD4600) to GTX970 in Biosi got an error
with some Xorg Gui.

However you can not install the Nvidia-Driver while X is running:
-> sudo killall Xorg
solves the problem

Then
-> sudo ./NVIDIA-x68xxx.run

After the first Driver Install (orig. Nvidia 352.xx) i had a blank screen.
Then i run the Nvidia Driver Installer again
-> sudo ./NVIDIA-x68xxx.run
This second install told me some kind of noveu driver is running and should be disabled. The driver asked me if it should disable noveu
-> Yes disable noveu

After restart: Et Voila lighdm is running again :)