# Ubuntu 16.04LTS extended display not working - 2 cards

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 16.04, dual-graphics

New build with 2 Geforce 710 cards and 3 monitors. Loaded Ubuntu 16.04. and with the standard driver all 3 monitors showed in system settings => display. But, experienced problems such as screen flicker, occasional system freezing and could not get i1Display to perform calibration. I downloaded/installed 364.19 using system settings => software & hardware but now only one display is active.
Followed the steps [Install Nvidia driver instead nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-nouveau) but still not working.

Interestingly, the mouse shows as an X on the other two monitors when I scroll to the left from primary monitor. However, system settings => display only shows one monitor.
The monitor that display is the only monitor plugged into one of the cards. The other two monitors are both plugged into the second card.

Does anyone know how to resolve?

Comment: Exactly the same problem with nvidia cards gtx970 and gtx1070. And nvidia drivers 370.

Comment: please post your xorg logs

Comment: Does this help at all? http://askubuntu.com/q/760934/274320

Comment: @Zacharee1 I tried this, but did not helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

Change the settings for each of the monitors there (on the first tab you see) and make each of them active as they currently may not be.  But you should also adjust the specific settings you wish for each one individually in the settings for each just below "PowerMizer".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this, but when I enable second monitor, it works, I can move mouse over it, but background is black and mouse cursor displays as "X" and I cant do anything there, and ubuntu settings does not displays this monitor as available. when I turn on Xinerama, GUI fails to run.

Comment: It sounds as if the default display manager may be taking over.  Here are instructions from within Ask Ubuntu for turning off the standard/base/pre-installed display manager so that your NVidia driver can take absolute control (but it assumes lightdm is the standard display manager in use for whichever desktop you have chosen to install, so change the package name if not): http://askubuntu.com/questions/320666/how-do-i-kill-the-x-server  That should remove the default oversight and control of your graphics devices by the Ubuntu basic display manager so that you can use only the Nvidia instead.

Comment: Yes looks promising, I'll try  to change display manager. Thanks.