# nvidia backlight brightness problem

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, brightness, backlight

**Problem**

Unity shows control while I press the Fn+Increase/Descrese brightness, but nothing happens. In console brightness doesn't work too while X server is running.

**Checked solutions**

I have tried ALL POSSIBLE solutions of this problem in google and nothing works:

1. write acpi_backlight in grub
2. reinstall drivers with apt purge nvidia*
3. write "EnableBrightnessControl=1" in xorg.conf
4. install nvidia-375.66, nvidia-378.13, 381.22, 384.47
5. "xbacklight -set X" doesn't work
6. changing /sys/class/backlight/brightness
7. update linux kernel from 4.8 to 4.10 and 4.12
8. replace EDID from old matrix (it breaks everything)
9. setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.0 3e.W=0 and then change backlight using Fn+keys.
10. xrandr --output DP-0 --brightness 0.5 --- bad solution

**My system and situation**

I used N173HHE-G32 display matrix in my laptop before and  everything was OK. But today I've replaced it to B173HAN01.2 and this problem has started. On Windows 10 I've solved it by reinstalling drivers on nvidia-376 from official MSI website.

So, I can see the next sequence: at laptop start brightness is maximum, then it is minimum (and working) while "initramfs ..." text is showing in console. And after X server starts brightness is maximum (broken) again. When X server stops brightness is working again!

```
MSI GT73VR 7RF, Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, NVidia GeForce GTX1080, B173HAN01.2 display matrix

uname -a 
4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1be0 (rev a1)
```

**However!**

But when I use nvidia-378 it **WORKS**! Unfortunately
 378 has a critical bugs after suspend mode in Unity interface :(((

Please help, my eyes are in blood (it's very bright for them) and I don't know what to do...

**Updated!**
After two years I understood that problem is inside of lightdm (or X server). When I stop it everything is ok...

Comment: Perhaps the best course is the 378 driver and fixing the suspend/resume bugs with it. What are the bugs?

Comment: Bugs with Unity interface - some artifacts around the borders of windows and menus. There is description - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1675597

Comment: I think someone said a month or two ago it has been fixed in version 381 or something like that. I think it was https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind who said it but https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6 I believe is another expert.

Comment: Bug with suspend is fixed, but backlight is not working :( i have tried 381..and many other versions..

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of: `for i in /sys/class/backlight/*; do echo $i; cat $i/brightness; cat $i/actual_brightness; cat $i/max_brightness; done`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You can find output for different Fn+Increase/Decrease here: https://jpst.it/11ETR

Comment: Can you include the output from `cat /proc/cmdline`?

Comment: Of course,  "BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.12.1-041201-generic root=UUID=9312900a-2d95-444f-b30a-245dc245f862 ro"

Comment: I had bad luck with `4.12` where Chrome `HTML5` would stutter when there was mouse movement in other chrome tabs and booted with `4.11.3` or `4.4.0-78` instead. I have ideas to try on grub kernel parameters but I'm on my phone now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62357/discussion-between-max-tkachenko-and-wineunuuchs2unix).

Comment: Possibly downgrade to the nouveau display drivers if nothing else works...

Answer (score 14):

### Update June 16, 2019

Last month, 2 years after problem was reported, OP discovered LightDM (Ubuntu Unity Desktop Manager) was source of problem. That said, in addition to the list below, there is another `grub` parameter that can be tried:

```
video.use_native_backlight=1
```

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04) for more.

---

### Original Answer

The ultimate reference seems to be in [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) which is a site I've turned to many times to fix difficult problems.

## Kernel Parameters

Looking at your `cat /proc/cmdline` there are no extra kernel parameters passed. The above link states:

Sometimes, ACPI does not work well due to different motherboard implementations and ACPI quirks. This includes some laptops with dual graphics (e.g. Nvidia/Radeon dedicated GPU with Intel/AMD integrated GPU). On Nvidia Optimus laptops, the kernel parameter nomodeset can interfere with the ability to adjust the backlight. Additionally, ACPI sometimes needs to register its own `acpi_video0 backlight` even if one already exists (such as `intel_backlight`), which can be done by adding one of the following kernel parameters:

```
acpi_backlight=video
acpi_backlight=vendor
acpi_backlight=native
```

If you find that changing the `acpi_video0` backlight does not actually change the brightness, you may need to use `acpi_backlight=none`.

***Try each of the `acpi_backlight=xxxx` options on your grub kernel paremeters line***

## When `xbacklight` doesn't work

You've tried `xbacklight` already and the link above addresses this:

On some systems, the brighness hotkeys on your keyboard correctly modify the values of the acpi interface in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness` (***As we tried in comments***) but the brightness of the screen is not changed. Brigthness applets from **desktop environments** (ie ***Ubuntu brightness setting slider bar***) may also show changes to no effect.

If you have tested the recommended kernel parameters and only `xbacklight` works, then you may be facing an incompatibility between your BIOS and kernel driver.

In this case the only solution is to wait for a fix either from the BIOS or GPU driver manufacturer.

A workaround is to use the `inotify` kernel api to trigger `xbacklight` each time the value of  `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness` changes.

First install inotify-tools. Then create a script around inotify that will be launched upon each boot or through autostart.

Below is script you need to create called: `/usr/local/bin/xbacklightmon`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

path=/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0

luminance() {
    read -r level < "$path"/actual_brightness
    factor=$((100 / max))
    printf '%d\n' "$((level * factor))"
}

read -r max < "$path"/max_brightness

xbacklight -set "$(luminance)"

inotifywait -me modify --format '' "$path"/actual_brightness | while read; do
    xbacklight -set "$(luminance)"
done
```

There is a lot more in the link above but these steps are a good place to start.

---

## Dedicated Forums

For additional support there are dedicated Linux Graphics forums:

- [Phoronix Linux/AMD/Nvidia support with many Ubuntu users](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/)
- [Nvidia Linux Developers Forum (with many Ubuntu specific topics)](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/board/98/linux/)

Comment: Thank you for a such big answer!
1) Try each of the acpi_backlight=xxxx options on your grub kernel paremeters line --- yes, I've tried it many times without any result.

Comment: Unfortunately, xbacklight doesn't work too :(

Comment: I think it's a drivers bug.. and I need somebody from nvidia dev team :)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the nVidia team who normally worked on the linux driver just got switched around, and there might not be the same linux support in days to come.

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush I recall last year Nvidia launched a forum specifically aimed at finding out problems users were having and working with them to solve them. Linux was their focus I believe. I went looking for the forum again today but couldn't find it. I did find two other support forums though and updated the answer with them.

Comment: What if I don't have a /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0 file?

Answer (score 3):

Per [wineunuuchs2unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix)'s request, I am reposting [my answer to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030526/brightness-on-laptop-msi-gt72vr-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-nvidia-gtx-1060-mobile-does/1043598#1043598) here.

## Try `acpi_osi=`

On upgrading to Bionic a few days ago, I encountered a similar problem (I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile, but for me `/sys/class/backlight` is showing as empty).

In working through [the backlight debugging procedure](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight), I discovered a workaround via kernel parameters:

- In "Software & Updates" → "Additional Drivers", make sure that you have `nvidia-driver-396` (or whichever metapackage is current; 396 is the latest at the time of writing) selected.
- Edit `/etc/default/grub` by running the command `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (optionally replacing `nano` with your favorite editor).
- Find the line that sets `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `acpi_osi=` at the end inside of the quotes.  On most systems this will leave you with a line reading `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`.
- Save and exit the editor.
- Run the command `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

(If these steps do not work, restore your settings by repeating the process, but removing `acpi_osi=` when you edit the GRUB configuration.)

Another workaround, if it is an option for you, is to [switch to a mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds).  In particular, I do not see the problem under mainline kernel version 4.17.

(Bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1775065).)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 2):

Hi I apologise if this is something the clever people have already ruled out, as I am far from familiar with the command line, but after a reinstall i hit this problem and all the above solutions didn't work for me
(MSI pe706QE nvidia 960m).

I was editing `/etc/default/grub` by:

```
gksudo 'insert editor of choice not in quotes' /etc/default/grub
```

and noticed the `nomodeset` was still sitting in the bottom of the file (I don't remember permanently adding it) and removed it.

save the file and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

all working again with shortcut keys #noobie fail
hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Sony VPCEH notebook, I had the same problem.
I tried this solution that worked for me: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221452#6

**Briefly**: With root privileges, create the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` with the following content

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 410M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Log out and back in again to test.
The link above also states: "If something goes wrong, simply delete that file and reboot to recover the system", but I didn't need that addition.

After logout and login the brightness control started to work again.
I hope it helps you too...

**or this one after works with ubuntu 16.04 under my laptop sony VPCEJ2C5E but with nvidia 378.13 i don't have use for the moment the 390.25 drivers.**

I was able to get my brightness keys working on my Lenovo W530 on Ubuntu 12.04.
These days X automatically configures itself, so creating an  xorg.conf file might make your system inflexible. Instead you can add a  section to a file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` and X will include that  section in the configuration that it automatically generates.
So to get the screen brightness keys working with your Nvidia graphics card, create a file in the xorg.conf.d directory, e.g:
`sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf`
Paste the following into the file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro K1000M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Log out and log back in, or reboot, and your brightness keys should now work!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

one program to solve all this problem !!!

i have GTX 1060 6Gb desktop ubuntu 16.04

NO need to do anything, just install brightness-controller with the ppa :

https://launchpad.net/~apandada1/+archive/ubuntu/brightness-controller/

solved the issue for me (see screenshots)
however it conflicts with redshift so you need to remove redshift

you can add it to startup for convenient use

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think this is not right thing, text is from site: "It is a software based dimmer". It's not control of your back light power, it's only software solution with RGB curves :(  I'll try it a little bit later.

Comment: try it, it really works :)

Comment: I have tested it. As I said it's software solution, it doesn't save the battery and it damages the picture color. 
xrandr --output DP-0 --brightness $VALUE --- do the same thing.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, a GUI is still nice to have though

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answers in this thread did not work for me. This did:

1. Make sure your Nvidia driver versions are right. In my case, I had the `nvidia-kernel-common-525` and `nvidia-kernel-source-525`, but was missing the `nvidia-dkms-525` package.
2. Add `nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` kernel parameter.
3. `sudo update-grub`.
4. Restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

clone this repo and paste the script `backlight.sh` into `/bin`. then make it executable and after this open a root terminal and execute the following command.

`sudo backlight.sh "brightness-level-number"`.

to clone the repository,

`git clone https://github.com/el-beth/backlight.sh.git`

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it uses "echo $1 > /sys/class/backlight/0/brightness;" and it's the same I wrote below "6. changing /sys/class/backlight/brightness"

Comment: it's not `/sys/class/backlight/0/brightness` the correct path is `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

Comment: or some other similar path for systems with specialized graphics hardware.

Comment: In any case it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You could install package of command xbacklight in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xbacklight

After installation you could use command xbacklight as follows:

> xbacklight -inc 20     # increase backlight by 20%
>
> xbacklight -dec 30     # decrease by 30%
>
> xbacklight -set 80     # set to 80% of max value
>
> xbacklight -get        # get the current level

Command xbacklight should work this way.

Comment: Sorry, but xbacklight in checked solutions list.. It doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed this and none of the online solutions that the original poster listed worked for me either. What did solve the problem was going to /etc/default/grub and in the line: 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Adding :

"acpi_osi="

But also do Not use "nomodeset" on it. Ppl added nomodeset originally to fix the software rendering issue, but this actually causes Linux to not recognize the Nvidia drivers.

Lastly make sure you go to the Linux Start Menu Driver Manager and update your Nvidia drivers to 430 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 05/2021

I have an Asus ROG GL504GS, and I encountered the exact same issue (I have a GTX 1070).
I fixed it with the solution brought by the first post : it was the service lightdm, blocking xbacklight.
So, there is to disable lightdm :

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Then xbacklight should work.

Note : I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, kernel 5.4.0-72-generic, and the Nvidia driver version 460.

Comment: It helped me too, but how to live without lightdm?

Comment: I personnally uninstalled it, and nothing happened... The Ubuntu documentation says : "LightDM is the display manager running in Ubuntu up to version 16.04 LTS. While it has been replaced by GDM in later Ubuntu releases, LightDM is still used by default in the latest release of several Ubuntu flavors."