# Cant change backlights after installing nvidiia driver

Tags: backlight, nvidia-geforce, xorg.conf

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.I have gone through an extensive search all night, but couldnt get anything fruitful. Before you tag the question as a duplicate, I firmly urge you to read throughly. My problem is, I can not change my backlight using the GUI slider. I have a system without an integrated GPU, only Nvidia GTX 1070. As I found in some forums (here included), I need to install the latest drivers. I did change to nvidia drivers from xorg ones. Now I cant even see the slider for backlight.

**Note:** I encountered a solution of an issue resembling mine (involving some changes in xorg.conf), but my gpu is **GTX-1070** ,**not Quadro**.For the link of the solution: [Backlight not working on Ubuntu 17.10, Lenovo P51, Xorg, NVIDIA Quadro M1200](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977353/backlight-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-10-lenovo-p51-xorg-nvidia-quadro-m1200)

Comment: If the machine in question is a desktop, just use the monitor settings to adjust brightness.

Comment: It is a notebook.