# Brightness wont go up or down and is stuck on max setting! Tried others solutions but still no fix! Please someone help!

Tags: grub2, brightness, asus, mint

I have a Asus Rog GL702VS-RS71 and I am having trouble with adjusting the brightness I have tried everything online that I could find but to no result.

Have tried the following...
Installing xbacklight and adjusting the settings on terminal(nothing happens)

gone into `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and done the following below each with no result.. And yes I have `sudo update-grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_video0="

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=acpi_osi"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=acpi_backlight=native"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=acpi_backlight=native intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

The splash screen shows with the brightness indicator going up and down but no solutions I've tried have worked yet. the battery applet in the bottom right corner doesn't do anything either if I move the slider up or down for the brightness

the only brightness that works when using the brightness keys is my keyboard brightness but theres already seperate keys for that and they work fine.. :/

PLEASE if you know the answer to this would appreciate the help so much!! As this is burning my eyes at max brightness..

Comment: Related questions: https://askubuntu.com/q/1045624/307523 and https://askubuntu.com/a/715310/307523

Comment: Still having an issue....
Anyone??

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `ll /sys/class/backlight`?

Comment: ll /sys/class/backlight
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Jun 29 19:23 ./
drwxr-xr-x 68 root root 0 Jun 29 19:22 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Jun 29 19:22 acpi_video0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/

Comment: What kind(s) of graphic card(s) does your laptop have?

Comment: It's got a GeForce GTX 1070
Any suggestions @WinEunuuchs2Unix bro?

Comment: Did you read this already?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/935585/nvidia-backlight-brightness-problem

Comment: You may also want to read this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-384/+bug/1720438 Let us know how things progress.

Comment: Read that and tried each things...
Still having issues :(

Thanks for trying WinEunuuchs2Unix...
No idea what else to try... this is beyond frustrating

Comment: Just found your question again whilst perusing **Linux Mint** tags. What version of Mint are you running? What is the output from `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux mint 18.3 cinnamon

Comment: Why not create a Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB and boot with that to see if it works OK?

Comment: Is my laptop too new spec for Linux at this time you think or what?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix any other options??
This is really driving me nuts
At the moment I just use redshift to atleast have that nightlight so its not as bad... but still being able to turn down brightness would be much appreciated

Comment: Use `xrandr` to discover your screen device names. Then use: `xrandr --output DP-1-1  --brightness .5` for 50%. Substitute your screen device name for `DP-1-1`
`

Comment: Thx bro, Am using redshift and managed to turn down brightness with this although its for the nightlight it helps atleast :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Software solution

In the question and in comments OP has tried many different hardware solutions to no avail. This leaves software solutions which aren't as effective but better than nothing. This script can be adapted for all monitors:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: alien
# PATH: /mnt/e/bin
# DESC: Set brightness of Alien Laptop
# DATE: Dec 9, 2017. Modified July 21, 2018.

# NOTE: Monitor name changes with driver used: nVidia = "eDP-1-1"
#                                             Nouveau = "eDP-1"
#                                               Intel = "eDP1"

MonitorName="eDP"
AllMonitors=`xrandr -q | grep -v disconnected | grep connected | awk '{print $1}'`
echo All Monitors: $AllMonitors
substr=ab
for s in $AllMonitors; do
    if case ${s} in *"${MonitorName}"*) true;; *) false;; esac; then
        FullMonitor=${s}
        printf %s\\n "'${s}' contains '${MonitorName}'"
    else
        printf %s\\n "'${s}' does not contain '${MonitorName}'"
    fi
done
echo Full Monitor: $FullMonitor

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
    xrandr --verbose | grep -A5 "^$FullMonitor" > /tmp/alien
    head -n1 /tmp/alien
    echo "$(tput setaf 6)" ; tail -n1 /tmp/alien ; echo "$(tput sgr0)"
    rm /tmp/alien
    echo 'One argument required for brightness level, e.g. "alien .63"'
    echo 'will set brightness level of Alien display to level .63 using xrandr'
    exit 1
fi

xrandr --output "$FullMonitor" --brightness "$1"
```

The script above was written for a three monitor system and addresses the laptop screen. Two other scripts (not listed here) are called "Sony" and "Toshiba" for two external HDMI monitors. The laptop can have Intel driver for i7-6700 HQ HD 530 graphics iGPU, nVidia GTX 970M GPU with different `xrandr` screen names depending on nVidia Proprietary Graphics driver or Nouveau Open Source driver.

Because the system has a total of 9 different xrandr screen names, three names for each screen, the script is flexible depending on how the machine has been booted.

To adapt this script to your needs:

- Rename script, eg change `alien` to `msi`
- Rename `eDP`, use `xrandr` to get list of all monitor names and select appropriate prefix. Enter prefix only into the script. It will find the `-1` suffix automatically.
- When calling pass parameter one for brightness level; `.75` = 75%, `.3` = 30%, etc.

---

### Keep checking new kernels for hardware support

Use these commands to check if hardware is supported after a kernel update:

```bsh
$ ls /sys/class/backlight
intel_backlight
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/*brightness*
3000
3000
7500
```

- The first `3000` is the actual brightness
- The second `3000` is the last attempt brightness change
- `7500` is the maximum brightness level for your hardware

To attempt to change hardware brightness level use:

```bsh
$ echo 2500 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
2500
```

If hardware is supported you will see a change:

```bsh
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/*brightness*
2500
2500
7500
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time WinEunuuchs2Unix very much appreciate your help