# NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 330M: Driver problem

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, 64-bit, overheating

My system (Toshiba Satellite A660-167 Core i7-740) overheats and turns off. This happens when I play videos online, YouTube or any other sites.

I used `Psensor` to check the temperatures. Normal temperature is about 70-80 Celsius. When I watch videos, the temperature gradually increases until it reaches 100° C and  the computer turns off.

I suspect this is a problem with the video drivers, but the driver seems to be updated. I have an NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 330M 1GB.

Comment: Consider reading [How to Install Nvidia Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/q/61396/159545).

Comment: @Akillos - You probably need a CUDA-SDK-1.1-driver by nvidia - this problem you describe might be solved with the posting (below) here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/311151/how-can-i-install-nvidia-driver-gt-520-and-cuda-5-0-in-ubuntu13-04/311154#311154

Comment: same problem here other GPU same CPU but overheating when playing videos or games. Already tryed several drivers no solution.