# How can I install Geforce 310M drivers Raring Ringtail?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I've got a problem.

I've installed Raring Ringtail, and have done all the updates.

However, my hardware, Geforce 310M, is not detected and does not appear in additional drivers (software update).

I have tried to install the driver manually, I got the source from here, thanks for that. 
But my Ubuntu gave some errors, so I re-installed again.

Can somebody help me? Sorry for my bad English, also I'm absolutely newbie Ubuntu user.

result of lspci | grep VGA :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [GeForce 310M] (rev a2)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include result of `lspci | grep VGA`.

Comment: probably duplicate of this solution for hybrid-graphics-cards posted here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/311151/how-can-i-install-nvidia-driver-gt-520-and-cuda-5-0-in-ubuntu13-04/311154#311154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried writing this on terminal?

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

These commands apply on ubuntu versions 13.04, 12.10 & 12.04! Hope it covers you.

Comment: After 2nd command, it give result :
<br>
'code'
W: GPG error: http://packages.medibuntu.org raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2EBC26B60C5A2783

Comment: @elhvdz Try this fix :

sudo apt-key adv –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys 2EBC26B60C5A2783              

Then type again the above commands in terminal that I gave you to install the drivers. The ppa I gave you is not outdated, so I assume it will work after this fix.

Tell me if it is all ok now.

Comment: W: GPG error: http://packages.medibuntu.org raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2EBC26B60C5A2783

Comment: So the fix that I proposed failed after trying that? That should have worked, to be honest. The error still persists?

`sudo apt-key adv –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv-keys 2EBC26B60C5A2783`

`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233199/how-to-add-medibuntu-public-key) as well, if mine does not work out.

Comment: i've done with do all that command, and I still have problem after install the driver. I decided to use Nvidia in future. Because I always failed in installing the driver. For starters, I just use the default vga