# nvidia 319.32 doesn't work with optimus

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 (3.8.030) and I have a GT630M card and I installed nvidia 319.32 from **Additional drivers** and restarted. But when I used Bumblebee with 12.04.2, I used to see 40-45 Celsius, but now it's 55-70 degrees.

I guess Optimus is not active. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: To check if your discrete card is turned off run in a terminal `cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch`. Also you should search for errors in the output of `grep bumblebeed /var/log/syslog` (or just update your question with the output of that command).

Answer (score 0):

You need driver package for Nvidia-CUDA-Optimus.

This is solved already by posted solution of me here :

[How can I Install Nvidia Driver GT 520 and Cuda 5.0 in Ubuntu13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311151/how-can-i-install-nvidia-driver-gt-520-and-cuda-5-0-in-ubuntu13-04/311154#311154)