# Cannot get Nvidia drivers working on Lenovo Y510P

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, lenovo

I cannot get nVidia drivers to load on my Lenovo Y510p. It ends up in either of 2 different states, either nothing loads, and I'm stuck in runlevel3, or I get a super low resolution desktop. I have tried every tutorial I could find (though most say the same thing)

If anyone has any insight, please help me out. I'm out of options.

Comment: Please add to your question an overview of the things you tried (*"every tutorial I could find"* provides no information to most readers, nor does the fact that most say the same thing). For instance, did you try the Nvidia drivers from their site?

Comment: @MatthewColeman - What nvidia-chipset is it exactly ? - in case of CUDA (sometimes with Optimus) then this solution here might help : http://askubuntu.com/questions/311151/how-can-i-install-nvidia-driver-gt-520-and-cuda-5-0-in-ubuntu13-04/311154#311154

Comment: I know it's not a solution but I've been able to use the Nvidia drivers successfully on Ubuntu 13.10 with nvidia-319. Nevertheless my current setup is with Bumblebee.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop has an Optimus NVIDIA card.  I suspect that installing Bumblebee is the ticket.

1) Add the repository to get new nvidia drivers:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
```

2) install the latest drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings-331
```

Install Bumblebee ([as explained here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation))

1) Add the Bumblebee PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

2) Install Bumblebee and its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

Configure bumblebee to use your new driver:

1) Open the config file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

2) Change the Driver, KernelDriver, Librarypath, and XorgModulePath like so:

```
Driver=nvidia

KernelDriver=nvidia-331

LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331

XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
```

Restart.

**EDIT2: Something to do if you can't use optirun (Bumblebee's method to invoke the Nvidia card)**

Edit the bumblebee nvidia configuration:

```
sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

Delete the "#" in front of "BusID ... "

**EDIT: If it still doesn't work**

You might need to change the parameters passed to the kernel. To test if this is the solution:

1. When you get to grub, select Linux (but don't hit enter.)
2. hit"e" on the keyboard
3. add "acpi_osi=Linux" to the end of the line
   that begins with "linux /boot/ ..."
4. Press F10 to boot.

If this works, you can make the change permanent by editing /etc/default/grub

1. type "sudo gedit /etc/default/grub"
2. edit the line with "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" so that it reads

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
3. Save and quid gedit
4. run "sudo update-grub"