# at 10 percent brightness my screen is at 100%

Tags: nvidia, hp, hybrid-graphics

I have Kubuntu 13.04 installed on an HP envy DV7 with the dual graphics chipsets intel 4000 and Nvidia 630M. And when I try to reduce my screen brightness it doesn´t actually go down until it reaches 10%. I´m running the standard nouveau drivers, no proprietary drivers.

Comment: Nvidia 630M is a chipset with CUDA ? Here is problem with CUDA (and Optimus) solved : http://askubuntu.com/questions/311151/how-can-i-install-nvidia-driver-gt-520-and-cuda-5-0-in-ubuntu13-04/311154#311154

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try it once.. It has solved all problems about brightness! Including mine!!**

- Open terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> ) and type:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```

  You will find this line in the new opened window: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- Change it to:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
  ```
- Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Restart your system..

Comment: you da man!!!!!