# Ubuntu 15.04 doesn't start with nvidia driver

Tags: boot, nvidia, gpu-driver, 15.04

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04 and since then when I use the proprietary Nvidia driver Ubuntu doesn't boot.

It shows "Starting 219" on my secondary screen and on my primary screen it shows something like "Starting Display Manager" and at this point it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383636/12-04-3-can-start-only-after-press-resume-in-rescue-mode-every-boot-proble).
I also reinstalled ubuntu but I think that wasn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the drivers. For some reason Ubuntu 15.04 seems to have an issue with nvidia drivers.

Here is my solution, tough its more like a "workaround"

[ACPI PPC Probe failed. Starting version 219 NVIDIA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613969/acpi-ppc-probe-failed-starting-version-219-nvidia/613989#613989)

Answer (score 0):

If you get stuck at something like "Starting Displaymanager", hold **Alt+SysRq** keys and press **R+E+S+U+I+B** sequentially to restart Ubuntu safely.

Then hold the shift key during boot to open the GRUB boot loader. In there, choose **Advanced option for Ubuntu**.

Now, try every option from below to the top, except **recovery mode** one. At least one kernel will be able to boot.

If you are able to login, **suspend** ubuntu instead of **shut down** unless some updates really need to **restart** ubuntu.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure which NVidia card you are using... I have to ask the obvious and maybe it was in another post if you have went to NVidia and downloaded the Linux drivers directly ?

Comment: @John75077 I'm using GeForce 840M and the driver is installed through Software & updates > Additonal Drivers > NVIDIA binary ... (proprietary, tested). The system was okay until kernel update.

Comment: I'm not the best at video issues, however this solution seems to address some graphics, X, and black screen problems. http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77525/en-us

Answer (score 0):

To improve the answer from dragon2fly...
On most keyboards, SysRq is PRTSCN (the print screen button).  So hold down the **Alt** key and the **PRTSCN** key while you type (in lower case, you don't also need the shift key) **reisub** (resiub should work just as well).  The system should reboot immediately.

I had the same problem as Marten, and for me, Ctrl+Alt+Delete did exactly the same thing as reisub.