# Graphical mode only in rescue mode after upgrade to 15.04 Kubuntu

Tags: nvidia, upgrade, kubuntu, 15.04

I upgraded to 15.04, now my GUI is blank when booting regular.

But I'm able to boot the GUI while selecting rescue mode.

```
apt-get update && apt-get-upgrade
```

Says everything is up 2 date

I have a Nvidia GeForce GT 740

Help would be highly appreciated!

**Update:**

I was able to switch to onboad card and rerun the Nvidia installer,
I also tried to enable the sddm service (as other recommended)

```
sudo systemctl enable sddm.service -f
sudo reboot
```

Also tried to boot without splash and quiet boot option

But now I'm sticking with a blank dark screen.

Comment: What did you mean by «blank screen»? Is it like this: you type a password in login manager, press enter, next the login manager disappears, but nothing appears intead?

Comment: No not even the login manager is comming up, screen stays at (Starting version 219) , but iam able to type some comments, and when i switch to onboard card i can see the console.

Comment: Found something, boot hangs at: A start job is running for udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization (1min 30s / 2min 58s)

Comment: [Try this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/391608/266507). Also, if that won't work, I'd try to wait a bit the hang, next press `Alt+Shift+PrintScreen+r` *(it ought to take the keyboard to you if the problem with Xserver)*, switch to a virtual terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and look at the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` *(you may want to post it here)*. To make sure that the «PrintScreen» combination would work, change the value in the `/etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an nvidia card too and I've been working with Kubuntu 15.04 since Beta2. During the first weeks I had to use the nouveau drivers because it was impossible to use my nvidia optimus and change to nvidia mode without the blank screen. After trying a lot of things and ask for this issue in the Kubuntu's google+ community, finally I have it working. The steps I did:

-In Drivers configuration I selected the nouveau driver to leave the nvidia propietary driver unused.
-Reboot
-In Accounts configuration I marked autologin in my user
-In SDDM advanced configuration I markedt autologin and select my user
-These two steps are to avoid the SDDM login screen that causes the issue with the nvidia propietary driver.
-sudo apt-get remove nvidia* (to erase all the files of my nvidia-340 version)
-sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
-Reboot
-After that, my laptop started up and go into the desktop without stop in the SDDM login screen. I searched for the nvidia-settings app in the K-menu and I confirmed that my nvidia was working in nvidia mode. I tested it with glxgears and I got 1700FPS when it was 50FPS in intel mode ou with the nouveau driver.

Hope it helps yo

Answer (score 0):

OP has solved the problem, taken from his question:

> I added **nomodeset** to my grub booting parameter, now it works
>   again.
>
> thanks for your comments!