# Ubuntu 16.04 Unity No desktop just background wallpaper

Tags: unity, 16.04

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 that I set to log in automatically. When it loads up all I get is the desktop wall paper but not top panel or unity side bar. Previously I was using Ubuntu 16.04 Mate edition and everything worked great. I read this question [Ubuntu 16.04 unity desktop environment doesn't load after fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760043/ubuntu-16-04-unity-desktop-environment-doesnt-load-after-fresh-install) but I could not get to a tty screen like the poster in that thread. When I did Ctrl+Alt+F1 all I would get is a blank screen. I've tried switching monitor inputs and going from my nvidia card to the onboard graphics but nothing seems to work. I'm just going to switch back to Mate for now but I would really want to check out what's new in Unity. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You can right-click on the desktop, and choose *Open Terminal*. That's what I did. Then I've removed the *compiz* configurations and cache as pointed out by @Jonayard, below.

Comment: This should not be set as a duplicate. None of the other solutions worked for me under 16.04.

Answer (score 68):

Fix compiz problem :

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
sudo rm -fr ~/.compiz
```

Then try this if your session not loading :

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.Xauthority
sudo rm -fr ~/.config/autostart
```

Reinstall compiz

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity compizconfig-settings-manager upstart
```

Finally clear the Unity Desktop :

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

This is how I fixed my problem hope it could be helpful to you.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that if I can manage to get a terminal window or drop into a TTY screen so far no luck though.

Comment: I think this is exactly the correct workaround. I had the same problem, I tried to use the guest account to log in it seems to be fine. I compared everything between the guest account settings and the root account settings. There is no much difference on compiz settings but Xauthority and autostart are different

Comment: sexy answer bro. Solved my problem.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a gentleman.

Comment: You're real gem!! Fixed problem in Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you very much. Mr. Rahman!

Comment: It's just unclear what cause the issue in the first place,

Comment: Why `sudo` on the first two commands?

Comment: This works for me, too.

Comment: This worked for me on 16.04 after trying many other solutions. This question should not be set as a duplicate because non of the other solutions work on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This works! You saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: It worked for me too, found a couple of solutions on other issues, but, only this one suggests to remove cache folder, and that was critical

Comment: Also worked for me on 18.04 with unity, great solution.

Comment: When I get to sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/, I get this error: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=....  --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

Comment: Worked for me on 16.04. The problem happened after an update but now all is well. Thanks a lot!