# Ubuntu 16.04 no desktop just background wallpaper

Tags: 16.04

Basically, every time I boot Ubuntu, no desktop loads, I just see the wallpaper. I don't know if its something to do with my graphics card (Nvidia GTX 970)? Someone help.

Comment: Has it been this way since you first installed Ubuntu, or was it working correctly at some point?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) .. see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/760356/ubuntu-16-04-unity-no-desktop-just-background-wallpaper?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Drop into a shell by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

Then try reinstalling the ubuntu desktop metapackage and then unity:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

Comment: I can't connect my wireless card to the internet because I can't get to the wireless connection menu from the taskbar at the top of the screen. The taskbar is missing.