# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop not loading even after trying multiple solutions

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, gnome, compiz

Okay so I have followed some of what other people are having problems with, but nothing fixed my own problem, so I shall detail what happened, what I did to fix and where I am now, if you can help that would honestly be perfect.

So I have a new desktop for gaming, but it has the following specs:
CPU: Intel i7 Quad Core,
GPU: Nvidia GTX 980 Ti 6GB,
HDD: 2TB,
SSD: 500GB

Now the setup is dodgy, as I don't have my monitors just yet, so I am using my TV which is 4K/3D (which I think may be an issue).

It comes pre-installed with Windows 10 on the SSD. So I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 onto a disk, put it in my computer and proceeded to install. It got through the install and then after the install it rebooted, the dual-boot works perfectly, and I loaded Ubuntu, got to the login screen, and I was still good. Then I logged in, this is where the problems came from, It came up with an error something to do with compiz, which I couldn't copy because ubuntu wasn't working, but I ignored it, to see if the desktop would show, which it did not. So I was able to right-click on the desktop and create a terminal and followed this topic: 
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

From the topic above I installed compiz after connecting and ethernet connection and attempted to re-enable the plugin, (found here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)) which I then set, apparently after doing so the desktop was supposed to spring to life, unfortunately this did not happen, I took the advice to do a restart, I did, after doing this I could now not actually right click the desktop anymore, nor was I able to create a terminal session, at this point I was unable to switch to TTY, because it could not detect my GPU settings. So some help from IRC, I booted into recovery and clicked FailSafeX which I then reconfigured my graphics drivers, to no surprise it booted into an empty desktop again after doing all of that and still could not get control of my desktop, but this time I was able to switch to TTY mode this time, so I ran the following: `DISPLAY=:0 ccsm &` and this errored and would not work, I wasn't sure of the error exactly but it didn't load. I then tried following this:
[Ubuntu 16.04 Unity No desktop just background wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760356/ubuntu-16-04-unity-no-desktop-just-background-wallpaper)

But again this did not work or do anything so I was lost after this point and I then followed another topic which said to install gnome and so I installed gnome (which I planned to do anyway as I do not like unity very much), once this was all installed it asked me to set the desktop display manager or something which I set to gdmXX (extra characters or something after)? (gnome I presume) instead of lightdm, now upon rebooting it does nothing. I get caught in what I can only assume is a pre-login loop, where I can't login anymore...

So my final thoughts is I am quite surprised that ubuntu doesn't just "work" or at least have a fallback resolution that it could display, now I have had problems with games GUI's not working because of running games in 4K but I was able to fix this, with Ubuntu I can't even get in to change the settings to change this, ao again I am lost, so any help would be highly appreciated.

My final thoughts are it's something to do with:
Compiz, Nvidia, My 4K TV, and gnome (now anyway).

Thanks,
Danny