# Latest compiz update for 16.04 breaks desktop + LUKS login

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz, encryption, luks

I just upgraded to the latest update for compiz and other packages, but that resulted in me not having access to a desktop at all! (can only see background and cairo dock).

I figured it was unity/compiz, so i reinstalled compiz according to [Ubuntu 16.04 Unity No desktop just background wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760356/ubuntu-16-04-unity-no-desktop-just-background-wallpaper)

Now i got my desktop back, but now shutdown button just logged me off instead. Its okay, i did this [Stuck on reboot and shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132143/stuck-on-reboot-and-shutdown/135568#135568)

Now I thought everything was okay, but i restarted my comp and upon reaching the purple LUKS ubuntu password page, I CANNOT TYPE ANYTHING!! Like it would not capture anything at all. I only managed to boot by going to advanced options in ubuntu --> recovery mode --> resume, which prompted a terminal like password page for LUKS.

Even then, by desktop looks really weird with only the menu bar displaying (no cairo dock, no nothing else and all the other configs seems turned off)

This is ridiculous. I cant even rollback packages cause i dont remember what upgraded. Is there a fix for this? would really appreciate help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since upgrading compiz yesterday. While I have no solution for the actual problem either, a workaround until then is to

```
sudo apt install gnome-session flashback
```

after logout or reboot, this gives you the opportunity to log into a metacity-based gnome session avoiding compiz (just click the new icon on the login screen to select it). Works fine for me.