# Error: invalid video mode specification 'text' Booting in blind mode --after invidia installation and update through apt-get update

Tags: boot, nvidia, recovery-mode

I need some help. After i install nvidia driver for my graphics Card **Inno3D GF-GT630** then update through `sudo apt-get update` and reboot. then this is now the display of my screen..
 *error: invalid video specification'text' Booting in blind mode*. I tried a lot of solutions but none of them work: like fixing through:

GRUB2 by adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='nomodeset quiet splash'`then update the grub.

[Recovery Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQqeA.jpg) in root(Drop to root shell prompt) and remove the nvidia drivers but it can't be remove coz it prompt "not installed, not remove,"  in screen and also i tried to mount remount the drive, update with apt but and error will appear and it says like error Fetching blah blah blah .. and the worst is i have only 2 mins to execute some codes in Root(drop to root shell prompt) in Recovery mode because this error [[OK]Stopped run ancron jobs and so on...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA2Kn.jpg) pops up and i have to restart again just to enter in the recovery mode again...by the way im using Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there other way to fix this? 
pls. help *im newbie*

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when the grub configuration (as can be seen by pressing 'e' for "Edit" at boot time) contained: `set gfxpayload=text`
Just removing it (manually, in grub) fixed the problem.
What's strange is that the same line worked before, on the same computer, before re-running grub2-mkconfig for the Nth time, not sure what happened.

This entry comes from GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text in /etc/default/grub, for the record.