# Booting in blind mode in Ubuntu 16.04 after two surge of voltage

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I have only one OS on my PC - Ubuntu 16.04.
My computer was turned on, after that there was a first surge of voltage and it began to reboot, but during this there was a second surge of voltage and computer began to reboot again.
After this I saw GNU GRUB menu with these options:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- System setup

I chose the `Ubuntu` option and then saw this message:

```
error: invalid video mode specification 'text'.
Booting in blind mode
```

After this nothing happens and the booting stops.

I already tried to enable and disable CSM in UEFI as written [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/882957/500160) but it doesn't give anything.
So, how can I fix it and boot Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

1. Boot your computer using LiveUSB or LiveCD, I used Ubuntu LiveUSB
2. Open terminal and execute: `sudo -i`
3. List disks and partitions: `fdisk -l`
4. Check first partition: `fsck -y /dev/sda1`
5. Check the rest partitions
6. Reboot from your main OS