# Desktop not responding (right click, icons, etc.) unity 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, desktop-background

My freshly installed 16.04 lts unity does not show on the desktop any of the files in the desktop folder, moreover it ignores clicking and desktop background setting. I could change the background only using the CCSM (compiz...).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

‎This is a different question, but its solution fixed my problem.

[Ubuntu 16.04 Unity No desktop just background wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760356/ubuntu-16-04-unity-no-desktop-just-background-wallpaper)