# No unity, no desktop, no laucher in Ubuntu Desktop 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher

I wanted to install `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity` packages on a fresh install of ubuntu server 16.04.1.
I installed with `ubuntu-desktop --no-install-recommends` parameters.

When I start OS, I’m prompted to log in with my user, BUT no launcher, no unity, no icons, no right-click, only terminal access and default wallpapers are displayed.

After login process, `.xsession-errors` start growing and CONSUME ALL FREE disk space ! this file contain only this error message:

> process 2473: arguments to dbus_message_iter_append_basic() were incorrect, assertion "_dbus_check_is_valid_utf8 (*string_p)" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-message.c line 2712. This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.

No log in `/var/log/syslog`.

Also, I can SSH on my machine, seeking on the web to find a solution, but no tip does not work for my case.

- [Ubuntu 16.04 Unity No desktop just background wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760356/ubuntu-16-04-unity-no-desktop-just-background-wallpaper)
- [GUI/Unity crashing in 16.04 LTS after updates 2018-01-04, compiz segfaults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults)
- https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-unity-no-launcher-no-dash-in-ubuntu-12-10-quick-tip/

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu, `ubuntu-desktop` (with recommended packages), `unity` without success, I'm lost.

Could anyone help me and save my day?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved my issue. It was a problem with **UTF-8**.
Modifify `/etc/default/locale` like this:

```
#File generated by update-locale
LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="fr_FR:fr"
LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8"
```

Reboot and it's good!

Answer (score 0):

#### I have ubuntu 16.04 and these are the steps that worked for me:

1) sudo apt-get update

2) sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop

3) sudo apt-get install unity

4) rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1

5) sudo shutdown -r now

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following [linuxslaves](https://www.linuxslaves.com/2016/05/fix-ubuntu-no-icons-panels-launcher-except-background.html), I moved the whole ~/.config folder and got unity back. First I tried the 5 steps posted by Bhagyashri Kulkarni, but this did not work for me.