# Cannot login into my session after trying to resolve no launcher no manu bar problem

Tags: unity, launcher, compiz, lightdm, login-screen

I had run following commands from terminal as the unity launcher and manu bar were missing, as given in [Ubuntu 16.04 Unity No desktop just background wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760356/ubuntu-16-04-unity-no-desktop-just-background-wallpaper).

Commands:

`sudo rm -fr ~/.cache/compizconfig-1`

`sudo rm -fr ~/.compiz`

`sudo rm -fr ~/.Xauthority`

`sudo rm -fr ~/.config/autostart`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity compizconfig-settings-manager upstart`

`sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

`setsid unity`

The manu bar appeared but not launcher. I rebooted my system but **can't login to my session**. When I login, the screen gets black and soon after that the login screen comes back. But the Guest session works perfectly (with launcher and manu bar) and I got the error

> unity-scope-loader crashed with sigabrt in g_assertion_message()

while using guest session.

In TTY when I logging in I'm getting message:

> No directory, logging in with HOME=/
>
> To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <"command>".

Does this massage normally appear in TTY?

Now:

- There is no .Xauthority file in my home (I have removed it)
- First 10 letters read exactly `drwxrwxrwt` on running `ls -ld /tmp`.
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` didn't work (can't run without `sudo`)
- When I type: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` It says:

  > error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY
- I tried `sudo lightdm`. It says:

  > The system is running in low-graphics mode

  Intel graphics is used in my computer.

Please advise on any way I can login to my session.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity

Comment: I had run sudo rm -fr ~/.Xauthority
sudo rm -fr ~/.config/autostart commands. Is this the reason for not login to my session?