# Ubuntu 16.04 No desktop and No Dash

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz, upstart

Maybe this question sounds like duplicate . But i tried a lot of them . But none of them work . 
I tried the following commands 
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager ( Error: package not available ) 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

rm -r ~/.config
rm -r ~/.compiz
sudo restart lightdm ( Error : Unable to connect to Upstart: failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart : connection refused )

export DISPLAY=:0
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity ( no package is installed named unity )

I can't remember the exact errors . But this is what i know . Anyone knows any good solution ? 
This happened yesterday after i installed GIT . After installation i kept it in this way . In the morning when i restarted my laptop suddenly there was nothing . Absolutely nothing . Any solutions ? This is my first post in askubuntu , i apologize in advance if i made any mistakes . THank you ,

Comment: Did you try this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/760043/ubuntu-16-04-unity-desktop-environment-doesnt-load-after-fresh-install?rq=1

Comment: @Nuwan For the first answer , i don't have NVIDia Graphis driver . For the second answer when i run setsid compiz terminal says setsid: failed to execute compiz