# Ubuntu 16.04 - cannot login, keep getting fsck message

Tags: boot, login, fsck

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 as a second OS alongside Windows 7. Installation process went smoothly and after it was done I also downloaded nVidia driver for my graphics card and installed it. Everything worked fine, yesterday I switched between Win7 and Ubuntu many times without a single problem, I've also set up screen resolution in Ubuntu to my monitor's native FullHD (which wasn't possible without nVidia driver) and everything was ok. I installed some software - KallistiOS and WineHQ. All was fine.

But today I tried to install `mono-devel` package which is sometimes required by WineHQ. I couldn't install it as I kept getting some error message (something about lock). I wish I remember what it was, but I just can't. I searched the Internet to solve this problem, I messed around a little bit trying to resolve the issue and when I restarted my computer for any time today I noticed the screen resolution change in login screen - it was back to 640x480 from 1920x1080. From there it got worse, because after typing in my password and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> I was briefly shown with `fsck` message saying that `/dev/sda3` is clean and after that I returned to login screen. Anytime I try to login this scheme repeats - `fsck` message is shown for a brief moment, after that system returns to login screen.

After searching the web I determined that the problem probably isn't with `fsck`, but that I'm stuck in a login loop. I'm stumped, because I don't know what to do to resolve this issue. I still have access to terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Removing `.Xauthority` with command `rm .Xauthority` (as someone here in another topic suggested) didn't help.

I didn't install any other graphics driver, so I'm pretty sure this login loop doesn't have anything to do with it (despite that resolution change). Unfortunately, I cannot check what the whole problem with Mono and lock was, since I was searching the Internet on Ubuntu and not on Win7 (as I can't login on Ubuntu). I also tried editing `/etc/default/grub` as written here: [12.04.3 can start only after press "resume" in rescue mode (every boot) - problem with Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383636/12-04-3-can-start-only-after-press-resume-in-rescue-mode-every-boot-proble/391608#391608) , but it didn't help, too.

EDIT:
This: [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: Was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process) the "lock" error you were talking about?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the lock error I got. I also tried doing what guy here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop suggested, but nothing helped.

Comment: Just in case, I did not delete the lock file, I only tried killing process.

Comment: If you have the symptoms of "login loop" but it is not solved by deleting the user's .Xauthority file, then the next things I would check are (1) that the user's home directory is writeable and not full (`ls -ld $HOME` ; `df -h $HOME`) and (2) that the user's desktop session exists (`ls /usr/share/xsessions/`). The contents of the user's `.xsession-errors` file may be helpful as well.

Comment: ls -ld $HOME gave me: drwxr-xr-x 21 radek radek 4096 maj 27 14:27 /home/radek. df -h $HOME shows me there's 40G free space available. ls /usr/share/xsessions/ outputs just this: ubuntu.desktop. cat .xsession-errors gives me a bunch of messages with the first one being: "openConnection: connect: No such file or directory". It also shows me that many processes were killed by TERM signal.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to reinstall Ubuntu, so the issue is gone now, although not resolved.