# Upgrade nvidia-settings on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, upgrade, cuda

I'm installing cuda. Among the dependencies, I have to upgrade my version of nvidia-settings 346.72 to be >= 352.39:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-settings (>= 352.39) but 346.72-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

How would I do this? I've already changed my nvidia drivers to be v352.55. Can't seem to find where to download an updated version of nvidia-settings anywhere.

Edit:
Previously installed nvidia 352 with:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

which installed nvidia-352, nvidia-352-dev, nvidia-352-uvm

Cheers

Comment: how did you install 352?

Answer (score 0):

You could look this link here, as there are already several good hints for what you search :

[Has anyone successfully installed CUDA 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x86_64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672047/anyone-has-successfully-installed-cuda-7-5-on-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts-x86-64/676772#676772)

Comment: I've looked through this. Thanks for the tip tho. It seems that my problem is unique on the recent annals of the web.