# CUDA 7.5 installation Problem

Tags: cuda

After installation of CUDA 7.5, ubuntu login is not happening. So that's why I'm following the below url,
[Has anyone successfully installed CUDA 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x86_64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672047/anyone-has-successfully-installed-cuda-7-5-on-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts-x86-64)

but in that scenario, lspci | grep -i nvidia returns blank.

Ubuntu Version: 14.04 with VMware.

Please suggest.

Comment: http://kislayabhi.github.io/Installing_CUDA_with_Ubuntu/ because I cant post a comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What OS are you using as Host?

You probably won't see any nvidia inside your VMware unless you use PCI passthrough, which is only supported if your host is also a Linux OS.

However, you can still install CUDA and compile CUDA code, but won't be able to execute it.