# Ubuntu 16.04 -- NVIDIA X Server Display Configuration ( No Scanout)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04. My laptop's GPU: NVIDIA NVS 5200 m (and the Intel one).I installed NVIDIA Driver version: 340.96 through

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
```

(the same one I find in the "additional driver" setting menu recommended by Ubuntu).

The installation was fine. But when I open NVIDIA X Server Setting. It seems the driver can't detect my laptop display (also my second Dell U2414 monitor). Under the "X server Display Configuration" tab, it is shown as “X Screen 0 (No Scanout). I've attached the screenshots below. and also the `xorg.conf` file content.

So how can I solve this problem? Thank you all in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/515994/nvidia-x-server-settings-only-shows-1-screen-laptop-external-monitor-connecte

Answer (score 0):

Hello ? Is this CUDA or Optimus featured Graphics Card ? Seems to be brandish new one ? Proceed only in case of CUDA or Optimus here :

You could try it with SDK-package of NVIDIA, but you would need to purge the installed drivers out of your system.

Do this all in recovery mode after you downloaded the SDK-package.

The link for more infos is here at workaround of myself :

[Black screen on boot when any NVIDIA drivers installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785695/black-screen-on-boot-when-any-nvidia-drivers-installed/884236#884236)