# Notepad++ all of a sudden very slow with high XOrg CPU usage

Tags: xorg, wine, snap, notepad-plus-plus

I started using Notepad++ years ago, probably when I was still on Ubuntu 14.04. It has been working perfectly until last October when, all of a sudden, the software became as slow as a snail. Opening it takes somewhere between 15 seconds and a minute. How long exactly varies.

Graphical components in the Notepad++ window load slowly, one-by-one. Especially the plugins manager window is very slow to load and there are hardly any plugins activated (only Mime tools, Npp Converter and NppExport).

During start-up the CPU usage of the *Xorg* process is high, 90-100%. It drops to 0-30% after startup and goes back to 60-90% when scrolling through a small text document.

My question is: how can I troubleshoot this?

Things I tried:

- Scrolled through the `/var/log/apt` history to see what was updated.  There was an update of snap `snapd:amd64 (2.56.2+22.04ubuntu1, 2.57.4+22.04)`, so my guess is that caused the issue.
- Upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Notepad++ using Ubuntu software center.
- Under Software & Updates → *Additional Drivers*, I tried to switch to a different NVIDIA driver. This failed with errors.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I installed Wine and Notepad++ manually and that gave me good performance again:

1. Install `wine`:

   ```
   sudo apt install wine
   ```
2. Install `windbind`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install winbind
   ```
3. In the home folder create the `.wine/drive_c/Program Files/notepad++` directory:

   ```
   mkdir -p "~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/notepad++"
   ```
4. Download the latest Notepad++ zip file from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/ and unzip it in the folder created in the previous step.
5. Run:

   ```
   wine start "C:\\Program Files\notepad++\notepad++.exe
   ```

During start-up I do see errors such as:

`0068:err:winediag:is_broken_driver Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.`

but it works and is again as as fast as it used to be.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/612388/618353) can help you solve the error you get.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog thanks, I'll have a look at that.